# Conditional statements after remote validation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, jqbootstrapvalidation

Using  the `Bootstrap validator` `remote`, fields are validated successfully. How can you then have a conditional statement if `valid` is true to perform a certain action and if false then do something else. This is my validator:

```
 agentPwd:{
     validators :{
         remote : {
             url : '/agent',
                    data : function(validator) {
                    return {
                        agentPwd : validator.getFieldElements('agentPwd').val()
                            };
                    },
                    message : 'Invalid user and/or password',
                },
            }
        },
```

I want to know how can an `if-else` statement will fit into here, such as one below:

```
    if(valid === true){
        alert('success'),
    }else{
        alert('fail'),
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various [events](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/settings/#events) you can listen to, such as `success.form.bv` or `error.form.bv`.

Comment: Thanks .....so something like this should work in addition to the above code:   

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(form)
        .bootstrapValidator({
            onError: function(e) {
                alert('fail'),
            },
            onSuccess: function(e) {
                alert('success'),
            }
        });
});